# how to call react component code from renderer.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, electron

Hi I am new to React/JS and Electron and would like to write a desktop application using these technologies.

The problem I am facing now is that I am not sure how to call react component code from renderer.js. I have such coding structure.

**electron-tutorial**

```
    src/
        components/Test.js
        application.js
        electron-starter.js
        mainWindow.html
    package.json
```

And this is a list of code snippet of each file.

**package.json:**

```
  "main": "src/electron-starter.js",
```

**electron-starter.js**

```
const application = require("./application");
global.application = new application();
global.application.run();
```

**application.js**

```
odule.exports = class Application {
  createWindow() {
    this.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1366,
      height: 768,
...
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "./mainWindow.html"),
```

**mainWindow.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
</body>
```

So from mainWindow.html I want to call renderer.js. I learned that I know I can call functions in such way:

**renderer.js**

```
"use strict";

const { shell } = require("electron");

function hoge() {
  console.log("hoge");
}

window.hoge();
```

But what I want to do is to call the react component below from renderer.js.

**Test.js**

```
import React from "react";

export class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello from Test class</h1>;
  }
}
```

Could you please help me ? Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0):

As you are just starting out, I would recommend that you use a boilerplate like [Electron-React](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/).